# Publishing Failed IOS Apple - Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, publishing, uno-platform

I am working on a project where we are using a Uno platform similar to Xamarin.
Now I finished the project and I got the certificate from the apple developer. I am using visual studio for mac and I am trying to update my app on TestFlight to start the tests, but when I try to archive, this error happens.

Error:
[image]

I already tried to increase the build on info.plist and to do other things that i found here:

[Failed to parse altool output: Failed to parse PList data type: /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440832/failed-to-parse-altool-output-failed-to-parse-plist-data-type)

but it didn't work.

Comment: Try to delete the folder **bin** and **obj** , then clean and rebuild the project . If it still doesn't work , re-start the VS and try one more time .

Comment: Thank you for the help, but is still not working.

Comment: Is your provisioning profile set to 'appstore' ?

Comment: Hi matfillion, i've seen about it, and the provisioning is already set and is still not working. I am keeping trying to solve it.