# Cant Publish Xamarin.iOS app to TestFlight

Tags: xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, testflight

So I have gone back and forth for 2 days trying to publish my application to TestFlight.

Publishing via Transporter shows success
[image]

Publishing via Xcode shows success
[image]

Publishing via Visual Studio for Mac throws this error
[image]

Yet when I go onto https://appstoreconnect.apple.com I don't see any build?
In fact sometimes its visible shortly after uploading (as processing) then it disappears
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440832/failed-to-parse-altool-output-failed-to-parse-plist-data-type

Comment: Have you set app-specific passwords? Here is an authentication error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue will lie within the email you should of received from Apple about the publishing failure.